# Random Guess game

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to make small random guessing game in PYTHON, it works fine however after the user plays I would like it to revert back to the start and allow the user to play again if "y" is entered. So it would revert back to the top of the code. I understand its a loop but i cant figure out how to make it work.
any help  is greatly appreciated!

```
import random



bet = input("How much would you like to bet?")
print ("You are betting €",bet,)

win = int(bet) * int(2)

print('Pick either 1 or 0')
number = random.randint(0,1)
guess = 0
while number < 2:

    guess_number = int(input('Enter a number:'))


    if guess_number == number:
        print('Your guess is correct the number is',number)
        print("you have won €",win,) 
        break
    if guess_number >=2:
      print ("Number too high")
    else:
        print("you are wrong, you have lost €",bet,)
        break

play_again = input("Play Again? y/n")
y = bet
n =  print("bye")
if play_again == y:
    bet
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the entire code (apart from `import random`) in a `while` loop.

```
while True:
    bet = input("How much would you like to bet?")
    print ("You are betting €",bet,)

    win = int(bet) * int(2)

    print('Pick either 1 or 0')
    number = random.randint(0,1)
    guess = 0
    while number < 2:

        guess_number = int(input('Enter a number:'))


        if guess_number == number:
            print('Your guess is correct the number is',number)
            print("you have won €",win,) 
            break
        if guess_number >=2:
            print ("Number too high")
        else:
            print("you are wrong, you have lost €",bet,)
            break

    play_again = input("Play Again? y/n")
    if play_again.lower() == "y":
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also put your code in a function as so:

```
import random

def game():
    bet = input("How much would you like to bet?")
    print ("You are betting €",bet,)

    win = int(bet) * int(2)

    print('Pick either 1 or 0')
    number = random.randint(0,1)
    guess = 0
    while number < 2:

        guess_number = int(input('Enter a number:'))


        if guess_number == number:
            print('Your guess is correct the number is',number)
            print("you have won €",win,) 
            break
        if guess_number >=2:
            print ("Number too high")
        else:
            print("you are wrong, you have lost €",bet,)
            break
    play_again = input("Play Again? y/n: ")
    if play_again =='y':
        game()
    if play_again =='n':
        n =  print("bye")
game()
```